# Can we get an object from single object key value in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of object - like this -

```
test: [
{
 id:'1',
 name:'A'
},
{
 id:'2',
 name:'B'
},
]
```

Suppose I have a value 2 that exists in object Test as id. I want to get whole object from array if id value exists in whole array

```
input - 2,
```

expected output - `{id:'2' , name:'B'}`

How Can we get it ? is it any possible solution ?

Comment: You would use `filter` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter
or `find`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: use [find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method: `array.find(obj => obj.id == input)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find object by id in an array of JavaScript objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7364150/find-object-by-id-in-an-array-of-javascript-objects)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)-

```js
const val = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'A',
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'B',
    },
];
const res = val.find(obj => obj.id === '2');
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

There can be multiple ways to do this. Here is how I did it.

---

```js
let test = [
    {
        id: '1',
        name: 'A'
    },
    {
        id: '2',
        name: 'B'
    }
];

let result = (param) => test.filter(el => {
    return el.id == param
});

console.log(result(2))
```

Comment: `filter()` returns an array of all matching objects and not the object itself as the OP is asking.

Comment: @pilchard `.filter()` method will work but as you rightly pointed out, it will return an array instead of the object itself but more importantly, Its not the right method to use in this case because it will unnecessarily iterate over the whole array even if the target object has already been found. `find()` or `findIndex()` methods will stop as soon as they find the target object.

Comment: Fair enough. I tried to put in duplicate ids and make it work. I guess id can be assumed to be unique.